# How to disable the deceleration animation of UIScrollView?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, uiscrollview

Is there a way to disable it, so that when the user stops scrolling the scroll view stops scrolling immediately rather than decelerating slowly?

Answer (score 0):

Just add this line in `ScrollView` delegate method (`willBeginDecelerating`).

```
[scrollView setContentOffset:scrollView.contentOffset animated:NO];
```

References
[Stop deceleration of UIScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2037892/stop-deceleration-of-uiscrollview) ,
[How can I programmatically force-stop scrolling in a UIScrollView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3410777/how-can-i-programmatically-force-stop-scrolling-in-a-uiscrollview)